# How does Packet Loss affect Ping (RTT) calculation?

Tags: networking, metrics, implementations

I am storing my Ping records in a limited queue, and I also have a cumulative sum to get the average. I'm doing it like a window.

My problem is this: Does it make sense that I have 5ms Ping with 98% packet loss? If I sent 100 packets but only two were answered and had a good response time, should Ping be the ones received?

One approach I thought was: Until I get an answer, I'm incrementing the time of the last element in my queue.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense that I have 5ms Ping with 98% packet loss?

Yes, it makes sense if your application doesn't care about the packet loss.

But if the application actually wants to know how well it can communicate on some higher-level protocol, then it doesn't make sense at all. In that case, it makes much more sense to measure the RTT directly using a communication channel with the same retransmission policy as the application protocol uses.

If your application uses HTTP, there are several possibilities depending on what you want to measure.

- If you want to measure the RTT of your actual requests, including the processing time on the server, then simply measure the time between sending a request and receiving the response
- If you want to measure the RTT *without the processing time on the server*, you can send a lightweight HTTP Request (like an OPTIONS request) and measure the time until you receive a response
- If you also want to exclude the HTTP processing, I would recommend using a TCP socket for the RTT measurement. That would be the lowest level where you still have the same retransmission policy and other QoS parameters as HTTP.

Comment: My protocol is HTTP, I consider a packet to be an HTTP Request. What would you do in this case?

Comment: @ÍcaroDantasdeAraújoLima, I have expanded my answer.